# Lync retrieve users location

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-2013

I have been trying to attempt to retrieve the location of certain users in lync (e.g. what building/site they are at) I have only been able to retrieve the whole contact card without filtering what site they are at. Does anyone know if this is possible or how I can go about doing it? I have tried to look this up for several hours but have only been able to come up with how to retrieve it as the logged in user and would prefer not to run a program on each PC to retrieve it.

The purpose of wanting this is so we can display on digital sign-age what First Aiders are on site at any given time so I need to query a list of users for their set location then display the contact card from there

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot query users based on contact card properties.

However, if you have a collection of "First Aiders", you could simply query their presence, grab the contactcard property and return them grouped by site. If you do not want to do this from every machine, make one machine act as a webserver or webservice and query that from your displays.